# GUI Cut and Paste

Tags: windows-10, win32

Does Cut and Paste GUI function in Windows10 use -r (recursive) method? Will it move the sub-folder structure with all meta data and other hidden attributes?

Answer (score 1):

Cut and Paste in Windows Explorer is the same as doing a move.

All sub-folders and all meta data will be conserved.